# Suddenly cannot create new openCV applications, windows 10

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-10

I have been using openCv for a while, but have just moved to windows 10.

Now, existing applications will compile, but I cannot make a new one.

In a new project (visual studio 2015, release 64)

I am adding all the libs:

```
opencv_calib3d310.lib
opencv_core310.lib
opencv_features2d310.lib
opencv_flann310.lib
opencv_highgui310.lib
opencv_imgcodecs310.lib
opencv_imgproc310.lib
opencv_ml310.lib
opencv_objdetect310.lib
opencv_photo310.lib
opencv_shape310.lib
opencv_stitching310.lib
opencv_superres310.lib
opencv_ts310.lib
opencv_video310.lib
opencv_videoio310.lib
opencv_videostab310.lib
```

setting:

```
D:\opencv-master\build64\lib\Release;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

and

```
D:\opencv-master\modules\highgui\include
D:\opencv-master\modules\imgcodecs\include
D:\opencv-master\modules\core\include
D:\opencv-master\modules\videoio\include
D:\opencv-master\modules\imgproc\include
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

and adding the most basic:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

    if (image.empty()) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

In visual studio, Intellisense is fine, no red underlines, everything looks good. When I try to compile tho...

```
'cv': a namespace with this name does not exist 
'Mat': undeclared identifier
'image': undeclared identifier
```

...and many more. It is like it cannot find the libs, but i am linking them correctly, I am sure of it.

Can anyone assist me here?

Comment: `D:\opencv-master\modules\highgui\include` -- That looks very wrong, looks like you're pulling partial include directories from the source code of individual modules. The build should produce the correct `include` tree. | Is that really the same thing as what you have configured in the "existing applications" that work?

Comment: It is,  yup.  What should these entries be?

Comment: I would expect there to be a single entry, pointing to the root `include` directory that the INSTALL target creates. This contains two subdirectories - `opencv` and `opencv2` (with further subdirectories for the modules). Look at the [standard distribution packages](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) to see how that include directory looks like. | The next thing is the fact that you link with so many different opencv libs, yet if those include paths are any hint as to what modules you actually use, then ~70% of those libs are absolutely useless there. What's the point?